# Mapping business Objects and Entity Object with reflection c#

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to somehow map entity object to business object using reflection in c# -

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

My Entity Class has same properties,  CategoryId and CategoryName.Any best practice using reflection or dynamic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [Automapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) or [Valueinjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/)

Edit:

Ok I wrote a function that uses reflection, beware it is not gonna handle cases where mapped properties aren't exactly equal e.g IList won't map with List

```
public static void MapObjects(object source, object destination)
{
    Type sourcetype = source.GetType();
    Type destinationtype = destination.GetType();

    var sourceProperties = sourcetype.GetProperties();
    var destionationProperties = destinationtype.GetProperties();

    var commonproperties = from sp in sourceProperties
                           join dp in destionationProperties on new {sp.Name, sp.PropertyType} equals
                               new {dp.Name, dp.PropertyType}
                           select new {sp, dp};

    foreach (var match in commonproperties)
    {
        match.dp.SetValue(destination, match.sp.GetValue(source, null), null);                   
    }            
}
```

Comment: i dont want to use any third party or open source

Comment: string destinationPropertyName =                  LookupMapping(sourceType.ToString(),destinationType.ToString(),sourceProperty.Name ) ;  Here  LookupMapping is Microsoft Dynamic CRM Function. how i can do it without CRM

Comment: i need to use reflection to avoid fix number of properties.

Comment: I wonder what makes you think it doesn't use reflection? GetValue, SetValue those are reflection methods.

Comment: @Aaabb Bbaa with Valueinjecter you would do a.InjectFrom(b) and that's it

Comment: I recently started working on a new project and found a copied version of this code in it. I would strongly recommend using AutoMapper or ValueInjecter as @Serguzest initially suggested as this piece of code created problems in our applications. For example, a List<string> would be null in the destination.

Comment: Tried your solution (in VB.NET but it's the same). I've added  "If match.dp.CanWrite Then" in the foreach cycle. Destination property could not have a setter. I also changed the method signature in this way to make the method more typed: "Public Shared Sub MapObjects(Of T, S)(source As T, destination As S)". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://automapper.codeplex.com/

My vote is for auto mapper.  I currently use this.  I've done performance tests on it, and although it is not as fast as hand mapping (below):

```
Category c = new Category 
  {
    id = entity.id,
    name = entity.name
  };
```

The trade off for mapping automatically makes it an obvious choice, at least for the entity to business layer mapping.  I actually hand map from the business layer to the view model because I need the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I wrote to do what I think you are trying to do and you don't have to cast your business objects:

```
public static TEntity ConvertObjectToEntity<TEntity>(object objectToConvert, TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (objectToConvert == null || entity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Type BusinessObjectType = entity.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] BusinessPropList = BusinessObjectType.GetProperties();

        Type EntityObjectType = objectToConvert.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] EntityPropList = EntityObjectType.GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo businessPropInfo in BusinessPropList)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo entityPropInfo in EntityPropList)
            {
                if (entityPropInfo.Name == businessPropInfo.Name && !entityPropInfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && !businessPropInfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual)
                {
                    businessPropInfo.SetValue(entity, entityPropInfo.GetValue(objectToConvert, null), null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return entity;
    }
```

**Usage example:**

```
public static Category GetCategory(int id)
    {
        return ConvertObjectToEntity(Database.GetCategoryEntity(id), new Category());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need performant solution, reflection may not be the right choice. In addition to the other answers, I can suggest using pre-compiled expressions because they are way more efficient and by using them you can benefit from type safety. You can read more about the idea in this [article](https://medium.com/@tonyslav_troeff/optimize-reflection-calls-in-net-408fe3df868f) on Medium.

You can also check out the `TryAtSoftware.Extensions.Reflection` - it exposes extension methods that can help construct appropriate expressions. It is [open-source](https://github.com/TryAtSoftware/Extensions) and available as a NuGet package.